# Rolling Running total over last 7 days by date and not bound by rows preceding but rather dates preceding for each row in a SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am struggling with a specific MS SQL Calculation.

I am trying to calculate the running total of the last 7 days for each date. However, there are sometimes gaps in the data so using a window function is proving difficult. I do not wish to sum the last 7 rows or entries, but rather sum by date.

As an example, the row with the date ‘2017-01-30’ should sum up itself and the preceding rows for ‘2017-01-24’ only, as that falls within the last 7 days.

I have tried several ways of coding this using a windowed function and also trying to left join this to a calendar table (that has all date in) but the gaps will still remain.

It is causing me a big headache as I am 100% sure that I am missing something - surely there is a simple way of doing this that I cannot figure out???

The data is in a table that has an ID column (bigint), date column (date) and number column (money).

Data sample (ID is excluded, it is not needed as it is non-unique and nullable):

```
DATE            NUMBER
2017-01-01      8.5215
2017-01-02      17.043
2017-01-05      8.5361
2017-01-09      8.6401
2017-01-09      17.2801
2017-01-16      17.6041
2017-01-19      8.652
2017-01-24      17.1984
2017-01-24      8.5992
2017-01-30      8.5317
2017-02-01      8.5536
2017-02-02      8.5463
2017-02-06      8.6222
2017-02-06      17.2444
2017-02-13      16.988
2017-02-14      8.4796
2017-02-21      21.2206
2017-02-27      8.5106
2017-02-28      8.5222
```

Example of result set required:

[image: maths example]

If any MS SQL Geniuses could help to write a little piece of code to save my life I’d be really grateful!

Thanks so much,

Shaun

Comment: This might help - [Date range rolling sum using window functions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/114403/7257)

Comment: Try my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Please upvote feature request to add support for temporal RANGE in window frame specification. It would make it trivial to implement. https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/aabbb0d5-9940-ec11-a819-000d3ae2b5ca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a [Calendar Table](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/calendar/145206/) this task becomes quite trivial:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (DateColumn date, NumberColumn decimal(7,4));
GO
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES
('20170101',8.5215 ),
('20170102',17.043 ),
('20170105',8.5361 ),
('20170109',8.6401 ),
('20170109',17.2801),
('20170116',17.6041),
('20170119',8.652  ),
('20170124',17.1984),
('20170124',8.5992 ),
('20170130',8.5317 ),
('20170201',8.5536 ),
('20170202',8.5463 ),
('20170206',8.6222 ),
('20170206',17.2444),
('20170213',16.988 ),
('20170214',8.4796 ),
('20170221',21.2206),
('20170227',8.5106 ),
('20170228',8.5222 );
GO
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT S.DateColumn, S.NumberColumn,
           SUM(S.NumberColumn) OVER (ORDER BY DD.Date ROWS BETWEEN 7 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS RunningTotal
    FROM DimDate DD --This is your Calendar Table
         LEFT JOIN #Sample S ON DD.Date = S.DateColumn)
SELECT *
FROM CTE WHERE DateColumn IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DateColumn;

GO

DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Comment: I didn't think of using a CTE to do it, this is what I am going to use to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This may helps:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE(DateColumn date, NumberColumn decimal(7,4))
INSERT INTO @Tab
VALUES ('20170101',8.5215 ),
        ('20170102',17.043 ),
        ('20170105',8.5361 ),
        ('20170109',8.6401 ),
        ('20170109',17.2801),
        ('20170116',17.6041),
        ('20170119',8.652  ),
        ('20170124',17.1984),
        ('20170124',8.5992 ),
        ('20170130',8.5317 ),
        ('20170201',8.5536 ),
        ('20170202',8.5463 ),
        ('20170206',8.6222 ),
        ('20170206',17.2444),
        ('20170213',16.988 ),
        ('20170214',8.4796 ),
        ('20170221',21.2206),
        ('20170227',8.5106 ),
        ('20170228',8.5222 )

SELECT T.DateColumn,T.NumberColumn Number
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN T1.DateColumn BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-6,T.DateColumn) AND T.DateColumn THEN T1.NumberColumn END) AggregatedNumber
FROM @Tab T
LEFT JOIN @Tab T1 ON T1.DateColumn IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.DateColumn,T.NumberColumn
```

**Output:**

```
DateColumn  Number  AggregatedNumber
2017-01-01  8.5215  8.5215
2017-01-02  17.0430 25.5645
2017-01-05  8.5361  34.1006
2017-01-09  8.6401  34.4563
2017-01-09  17.2801 34.4563
2017-01-16  17.6041 17.6041
2017-01-19  8.6520  26.2561
2017-01-24  8.5992  34.4496
2017-01-24  17.1984 34.4496
2017-01-30  8.5317  34.3293
2017-02-01  8.5536  17.0853
2017-02-02  8.5463  25.6316
2017-02-06  8.6222  42.9665
2017-02-06  17.2444 42.9665
2017-02-13  16.9880 16.9880
2017-02-14  8.4796  25.4676
2017-02-21  21.2206 21.2206
2017-02-27  8.5106  29.7312
2017-02-28  8.5222  17.0328
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a technique which generates a join table in a CTE which uses DATEADD to determine which dates to join to each row then uses this to do a self join to get the sum. no need for window functions.

```
WITH Sample
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM 
    (
        VALUES 
        ('2017-01-01', 8.5215),
        ('2017-01-02', 17.043),
        ('2017-01-05', 8.5361),
        ('2017-01-09', 8.6401),
        ('2017-01-09', 17.2801),
        ('2017-01-16', 17.6041),
        ('2017-01-19', 8.652),
        ('2017-01-24', 17.1984),
        ('2017-01-24', 8.5992),
        ('2017-01-30', 8.5317),
        ('2017-02-01', 8.5536),
        ('2017-02-02', 8.5463),
        ('2017-02-06', 8.6222),
        ('2017-02-06', 17.2444),
        ('2017-02-13', 16.988),
        ('2017-02-14', 8.4796),
        ('2017-02-21', 21.2206),
        ('2017-02-27', 8.5106),
        ('2017-02-28', 8.5222)
        ) AS DataSample(Date, Number)
),
TALLY
AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (0),(-1),(-2),(-3),(-4),(-5),(-6)) AS a(Num)
),
IncludedDates
As
(

    SELECT [Date], DateAdd(d, Tally.Num, [Date]) AS IncludeDate
    FROM Sample
    CROSS APPLY TallY
)
SELECT S1.[Date], SUM(s2.Number) as Total
FROM Sample S1
INNER JOIN IncludedDates ID
    ON S1.[Date] = Id.[Date]
INNER JOIN Sample S2
    ON S2.[Date] = ID.[IncludeDate]
--WHERE S1.[Date] = '2017-01-30'
GROUP BY s1.[Date]
```